# Gvim shell problem

Tags: vim

I have been using Gvim for quite sometime and I like it very much.
There is a problem I am facing with Gvim.
I type "shell" and go to the command line, When I press the up arrow I get some weird
symbols and I am not able to use backspace also.
The version which I am using.
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Mar 19 2009 15:27:51)

Comment: What operating system? What shell?  How did you start gvim?

Comment: My operating system is Ubuntu 9.04. When I say 'echo $SHELL' in my command line I get '/bin/bash'. Is this the one which you are asking? I start Gvim by click the icon.

Comment: I have this same problem. It's almost a deal breaker for me. And I just got gvim set up perfectly.

Comment: @puk I got conqueTerm installed, and it saved me. Try it :)

Comment: @DeepakPrasanna thanks! It boggles my mind that things like this don't come standard with vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly the reason this is not working is because gvim  is an  editor, not a terminal emulator.  When yoy type :shell in gvim, you do not actually get a shell, you get some weak shell emulation.  I say 'weak' because that shell emulation does not know how to deal with color codes, clear the screen or much else.

I stick to terminal vim, that way I can either use :shell, or, as is much more common, ^Z to just drop back into my shell to do something ( ^Z == suspend ) That, plus gnu-screen, plus a good shell is all the IDE I want.

Comment: agreed, but there is another bunch of problems with terms, e.g. for colors and mappings. So, someone might consider gVim over it.

Comment: How hard would it be to run a terminal inside a text editor? Gedit does it for crying out loud =P

Comment: Well, actually you run text editors inside of shells, right? ^Z is the equivalent of Apple's  CMD-<TAB>, and the communication happens over text streams.

Answer (score 2):

Try some wrappers, e.g. [Conque Shell : Run interactive commands inside a Vim buffer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) ;)

Comment: Whatever you do, **NEVER** open a vim session from inside a Conque Shell session. you can never get out of it without deleting the whole buffer

Answer (score 0):

vim is not for such complicated things I think. you can do simple shell operation via :! or :shell, However, vim is only a good if not best editor. 
What you need can be done in shell-mode of Emacs.